# Click and hold event Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onclick, onclicklistener

I havent gotten started on the project I'm going to be working on, but in planning I'm having trouble figuring out a click and hold event issue.

I am going to be having a click through div (a div that is over the image element, yet I can still click on the image) with an opacity somewhere around 0.7 with an image below it. I will be able to click on the image and move it around on a canvas (basically just move it from one side of the canvas to the other).

Does anyone know of a way to create a click and hold event where when I am clicking on the image to move it on the canvas, the click through divs opacity becomes 0 (or the div become hidden all together), then when i un-click it goes back to 0.7?

Thanks!

Comment: `mousedown` and `mouseup` events?

Comment: by saying *canvas* you mean a HTML5 `<canvas>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please try this**

I have created a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/9dx1cxu8/12/) . This is what I understood from your question. If this is not what you meant please add some html or code you have tried so that its easy to understand your problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").mouseup(function(){
        $("#containment-wrapper").css("background-color", "black");
    });
    $("img").mousedown(function(){
        $("#containment-wrapper").css("background-color", "white");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for doing this! this actually not that part the question is about. I wish i had enough points to put an image up I could easily explain it that way.

Basically image that I have a div that takes up the entire width and height of the browser, its black, and slightly opaque. underneath that div i have an image (the image is clickable though the black opaque div). When I click on that image I want the black (top) div to be hidden (or opacity: 0) and when I un-click I want the opacity to go back to the original opacity.

Comment: @Midi_ I have updated the code. Verify my latest "DEMO"

Comment: Thank yo so much Rino! I didn't know about the mouseup mousedown functionality. I really appreciate it, this is exactly what I was looking for! Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

What about jQuery's https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/ ?
In the Doc they have an example how to bind the even to a target:

```
$( "#target" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
    var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
    msg += event.pageX + ", " + event.pageY;
    $( "#log" ).append( "<div>" + msg + "</div>" );
});
```