# Click and hold event in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

I'd like to be able to have a function attached to an element which will only run once a click has been held on that element for a given amount of time.

There are several ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40573922/click-and-hold-event-listener-with-javascript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398294/click-and-hold-event-javascript), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18584389/listen-to-mouse-hold-event-on-website)) questions relating to handling mouse holds in javascript; but these questions either use jQuery or relate to a more particular use case.

I'd like to implement something more general, and I feel like there ought to be a good answer on stack overflow for this problem.

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158847/how-to-simulate-key-presses-or-a-click-with-javascript)

Comment: @RyanWilson I think I'm missing something; that question relates to simulating key presses, is there anything related to handling mouse holds in there?

Comment: As your code snippet is working, you should ask your question in the [Code Review SE community](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think your implementation is ok, I don't think there's any shorter or built-in version

Comment: In order to implement a hold, you need to listen for mouse down and time how long it is before a mouse up. That's exactly what your code does, and quite tidily besides. Maybe you can just inline the `removeUpListener` call since that's a one-liner that is only called in one place, but realistically there's not much else to improve.

Comment: Maybe use `Date.now()` instead of `new Date()` as well.

Comment: @KévinBibollet I think you may be right that this is perhaps better on code review. I suppose there are three options: `1.` Remove the code from my question and add it as an answer. `2.` Ask the question on code review. `3.` Delete this question and answer one of the old questions. I have a bit of an aversion to the Code Review SE, and as I say, the old questions aren't really ideal either. I could delete the code from here and post it as an answer?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thank you for your input; I think you're right about both of those, I may move my code to an answer in order to better fit with how SO ought to work

Comment: @RyanWilson Sorry, I'm not sure I follow; I'm not looking to simulate a key hold, but to respond to one.

Comment: @RyanWilson thanks for the suggestion; but that question's answer relies on jQuery, which is something I'd like to avoid

Comment: @OliverRadini It does use JQuery, but you can always translate it to plain javascript.

Comment: @RyanWilson That's kind of the point of this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function handleClickHold(el, timeout, callback) {
  let startTime;
  const mouseDown = () => (startTime = Date.now());
  const mouseUp = (e) => Date.now() - startTime > timeout && callback(Date.now() - startTime);
  el.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
  el.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseUp);
}

const timeout = 500 // time in ms
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const callback = (ms) => console.log('Held Button for ' + ms + ' ms')
handleClickHold(btn, timeout, callback);
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

If you want something more general use, you could use a function like this. Takes an element, a timeout, and a callback, so you can apply it in different situations. You can pass the event to the callback as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I get using window.setTimeout :

```js
  var mouseTimer;
  var myVar;
  function mouseDown() { 
      mouseTimer = window.setTimeout(myFunction,500); //set timeout to fire in 2 seconds when the user presses mouse button down
  }

  function myFunction(){ myVar = true;}
  var div = document.getElementById("testBtn");
  testBtn.addEventListener("mousedown", mouseDown);
  document.body.addEventListener("mouseup", removeTimer);  
  
  function removeTimer(){
     if(myVar) console.log("a");  
     if (mouseTimer) window.clearTimeout(mouseTimer);
     myVar = false;
     
   }
```

```html
<button id="testBtn">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it, though it feels rather verbose:

```js
const addHoldListener = (element, f, timeout) => {
  let down = 0;
  let up = 0;

  const upListener = () => {
    up = Date.now();
    const diff = up - down;

    if (diff >= timeout) {
      f();
    }

    element.removeEventListener('mouseup', upListener);
  };
  
  const downListener = () => {
    down = Date.now();
    element.addEventListener('mouseup', upListener);
  };
  
  element.addEventListener('mousedown', downListener);
};

addHoldListener(
  document.querySelector('button'),
  () => console.log('a'),
  500
)
```

```html
<button>Test</button>
```